# GeoDjango save data from json or points

Tags: django, geodjango

If I already have existing MultiString cordinates in a file(as a list) or memory or in a json format,
How do I override the save function to save these points instead of the user creating the object on a map? Or perhaps more precisely, how do i load these points to a model and the database?

Coordinates in memory/file

```
[[36.66678428649903, -1.5474249907643578], [36.670904159545906, -1.542620219636788], [36.66635513305665,-1.5353272427374922],[36.662406921386726, -1.5403894293513378]]
```

models.py

```
class LogsUpload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    geom  = gis_models.MultiLineStringField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How do I use the cordinates and save them in the geom field?

Comment: Are you trying to save the geographic data as: several points each with its own data? one collection of line strings? a single line string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PointField` of **gis.db** for storing `[lat, long]` data.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_model

geom = gis_model.PointField(null=True, spatial_index=True, geography=True)
```

PointField accept GEOSGeometry object, so you can create your data like.

```
import json
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

data_coordinates = [[36.66678428649903, -1.5474249907643578], [36.670904159545906, -1.542620219636788], [36.66635513305665,-1.5353272427374922],[36.662406921386726, -1.5403894293513378]]

for coordinate in data_coordinates:
    point = {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": coordinate 
    }
    
    LogsUpload.objects.create(name="your location name", geom=GEOSGeometry(json.dumps(point)))
```

> **Read more**: [Storing, querying & serializing location data with Django using PostGIS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/)

**UPDATE**

If you want to save all of them in one object of `LogsUpload` model, you can simply use [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) or [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) of `django.db.models`

Comment: Thanks Satendra.  But just to clarify, I have multiple lat/longs that are from a polyline, and I want to store all of them. Doesnt PointField only store one point?

Comment: Do You want to save all lat/longs  in one object of LogsUpload?

Comment: Yes I want to save all of them in the model.

Comment: If you want to save all of them in one object of LogsUpload model, you can simply use [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) or [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) of `django.db.models`

Comment: @Satendra Link does not work. Can you update the link?

Answer (score 3):

Use `LineString` and `MultiLineString` classes from the [GEOS API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos/) to create lines and multi-lines in memory, and assign them to your model's fields:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import LineString, MultiLineString
>>> DATA = [[36.66678428649903, -1.5474249907643578], [36.670904159545906, -1.542620219636788], [36.66635513305665,-1.5353272427374922],[36.662406921386726, -1.5403894293513378]]
>>> line = LineString(DATA)
>>> line
<LineString object at 0x7f96538f49a0>
>>> line.length
0.02134446840090856
>>> line.geojson
'{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 36.666784286499031, -1.547424990764358 ], [ 36.670904159545906, -1.542620219636788 ], [ 36.666355133056648, -1.535327242737492 ], [ 36.662406921386726, -1.540389429351338 ] ] }'
>>> multi_line = MultiLineString(line)
>>> multi_line
<MultiLineString object at 0x7f96536ccbc0>
>>> multi_line[0]
<LineString object at 0x7f964187b3c8>
>>> multi_line.length
0.02134446840090856
>>> multi_line.geojson
'{ "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 36.666784286499031, -1.547424990764358 ], [ 36.670904159545906, -1.542620219636788 ], [ 36.666355133056648, -1.535327242737492 ], [ 36.662406921386726, -1.540389429351338 ] ] ] }'

>>> from myapp.models import LogsUpload
>>> o = LogsUpload(name="foo", geom=multi_line)
>>> o.full_clean()
>>> o.save()
```

Tested with Django 2.0 and PostGIS.